# Concurrent futures webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I am currently trying to develop a fast webscraping function so I can scrape a large list of files.

This is the code I have currently:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
def parse(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup.find_all('a')
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    start = time.time()
    futures = [ executor.submit(parse, url) for url in URLs ]
    results = []
    for result in as_completed(futures):
        results.append(result)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time Taken: {:.6f}s".format(end-start))
```

this brings backs results for websites i.e [www.google.com](http://www.google.com),
however my problem is I have no idea to view the data it brings back
I only get future objects.

Please can someone explain/show me how to do this.

I appreciate anytime you give to help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it by dict comprehension also, like below.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:

    start = time.time()
    futures = { executor.submit(parse, url): url for url in URLs }
    for result in as_completed(futures):
        link = futures.get(result)
        try:
            data = result.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            print("Link: {}, data: {}".format(link, data))
    end = time.time()
    print("Time Taken: {:.6f}s".format(end-start))
```